# Does E*Trade Bank have an API?

Tags: api, banking

Does E*Trade Bank (*not* E*Trade Securities) offer an API of any sort? For example, one that would allow programmers to retrieve a savings account balance?

I've also [sent them an email](https://us.etrade.com/e/t/welcome/customerservice) asking the same question, and am waiting to hear back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone from E*Trade just called me up to tell me that no, E*Trade Bank does **not** have an API.